# Multiplicar 2 columnas usando laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-excel

Estoy intentado exportar un archivo de excel en laravel, sin embargo hay una parte que nose como resolver. Tengo la siguiente linea en mi `Export`

```
public function query()
{   
    return Lubricantes::where('fecha', $this->date)->select(['nombre', 'cantidad', 'costo']);
}
```

Es simple y me trae los datos que quiero pero ademas necesito que me traiga en otra columna el producto de `cantidad` y `costo` cosa que no he podido lograr.

**edito:**
Bueno intente esto:

```
public function query()
{   
    return Lubricantes::where('fecha', $this->date)->select(['nombre', 'cantidad', 'costo', 'costo * cantidad as total']);
}
```

y esto:

```
public function query()
{   
    $data = DB::table('lubricantes')->where('fecha', $this->date)->select(['nombre', 'cantidad', 'costo', DB::raw('(costo * cantidad) as total')]);
    return $data;
}
```

esta ultima me muestra este error

> You must specify an orderBy clause when using this function.

y esta es la query que use en el `mysql` y que me trajo los valores como los queria:

```
SELECT nombre, cantidad, costo, (costo * cantidad) AS total FROM `lubricantes` WHERE fecha = ?
```

Comment: Probaste agregarle un orderBy?

Answer (score 0):

si lo que quieres es mostrar estos datos en una vista algo así:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Costo</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($lubricantes as $lubricante)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$lubricante->nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{$lubricante->cantidad}}</td>
                <td>{{$lubricante->costo}}</td>
                <td>{{$lubricante->total}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Yo te recomendaría usar un [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) que lo que hace es transformar un atributo o crear uno.

en tu modelo Lubricantes colocarías algo así:

```
public function getTotalAttribute()
{
    return $this->cantidad * $this->costo;
}
```

De esta manera ya existe el atributo total y puedes ejecutar en tu vista:

```
$lubricante->total;
```

y si lo que quieres es retornar ese atributo en un JSON simplemente en el modelo agregas:

```
protected $appends = ['total'];
```